# Programmatically copy array to new view in Storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am currently trying to copy an array I have to a new view that I am creating programmatically.  I actually have found how to do this with normal navigation controller syntax.  My issue is I'm using the new storyboard and I don't know the syntax to do the same thing.  Here is the code I have..

```
CustomerListViewController *second = [[CustomerListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomerListViewController" bundle: nil];
[second setValue:customerList.list];
// [self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:YES];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginSegue" sender:self];
```

as you can see, I am programmatically creating the second view controller and storing the local array customerList.List to the created view controller's array variable.  The next step is to open the new created view.  The line commented out is the syntax to open the view under a navigation controller.  The line below is the storyboard way, but minus specifying the view I created.  I need to know the syntax for the storyboard to do the same thing as the navigation controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not make sense to create your own instance of `CustomerListViewController` here if you're using segues. The segue itself will create the view controller from the storyboard and the instance you have created here will do nothing.

Instead, just call `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` here. Then implement the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"LoginSegue"]) {
        CustomerListViewController *destinationController = (CustomerListViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        [destinationController setValue:customerList.list];
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned.. I need to programatically call the segue at a specific time because the new view is called under a button press but I have to open a connection, and do some processing and calculations.  If I don't call it programatically, then the view opens before any of those calculations are done and my array is empty when the view is created.  *edit* Nevermind, I see what you are saying.  I'll try this out.

Comment: No problem. As I said, just call `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` when you need to start the segue.

Comment: Well I tried this out and first, the code you posted causes an error on customerList.list saying customerList is undefined(which it is in the 2nd view controller).  I changed it to just list(the name of the array in the 2nd view controller) but its empty and nothing is passed.  With this style, I guess I'm not seeing where exactly the array from the first view controller is being passed to the second...

Comment: `prepareForSegue:sender:` must be a method in the originating view controller (the same where you call `performSegue...` from). If `customerList.list` is not available in that method, you should either make it an ivar/property in the view controller or share the value from one method to the other via the `sender` param.

Comment: Oooh my mistake, I put it in the 2nd view controller.  Seems to work!

thanks a lot!