# Different behavior in accessing Views via Tabs or Segues

Tags: ios, tabs, refresh, behavior, segue

I'm facing the following problem during the implementation of my app.
I've a tabbed application and clicking on each tab I can access to the corresponding view: for example, clicking on tab2 opens view2. But I can access to view2 also by clicking on a button on the view1 that is made as follows:

```
...
[buttonToView2 addTarget:self action:@selector(gotoView2) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
...
```

where:

```
- (void)gotoView2
{
    //execute segue programmatically
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"View2Segue" sender: self];
}
```

View2 has a table that shows data of an array populated with data from the internet (in `viewDidAppear` method).
So, both selecting tab2 or clicking the button should bring the user to the destination view2.

This works but has a different behavior in the two cases:

- If I click on the tab, the table is already populated with data while the application retrieves information from the internet
- If I click the button and I perform the segue, the table is empty while the application retrieves information from the internet

Why? Maybe because of selector invoked by the button is executed on a different thread?
Any ideas please?

Regards,
yassa

Comment: Ensure you've correctly implemented `-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` for your seque (see helpful post?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680453/programatically-copy-array-to-new-view-in-storyboard)

Comment: In this case I didn't implement the `prepareForSegue` since I've no information that must be passed to the destination view2...

I'll try to explain better. I have: `@interface View2 : UIViewController
{
    NSArray *arrayView2;
    UIImage *profileImage;
    ....`
If I access to this view via tab for the second time, all these variable are populated. If I access programmatically via Segue, they're nul.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime a Segue is performed it creates a new instance of the destinationViewController (in this case view2). Meaning you have 2 separate instances of view2.

Comment: and is it possible to avoid this in some way? or is there a workaround for this? Thanks for your answer!!!

Comment: there is no way to avoid what Segue's do. But maybe think of redesign the flow of your app. For instance you could have the button programically switch to the second tab instead of performing the segue.

Comment: do you mean something like this:

`View2 *currentImageDetail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View2Identifier"];
[self.View1 addSubview:currentImageDetail.view];`
or are there better ways? Thanks a lot!!!